# How to develop nested condition query in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am pretty new to mongoDb and want to apply nested query.

I have a business schema like this:

```
const businessSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    businessType: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "businessCategory",
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      select: false,
    },
    
    review: {
      type: [reviewSchema],
    },
    isDeleted: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

Business has a review where user can do the review and reviewSchema is

```
const reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "users",
      required: true,
    },
    rating: {
      type: Number,
      enum: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    },
    reviewArray: {
      type: [singleReviewSchema],
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

One user can do many reviews, and it has reviewArray.

ReviewArray schema is

```
const singleReviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
    },
    isDeleted: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

How to fetch the business with a condition `business: isDeleted:false` and its reviews with `singleReviewSchema: isDeleted:false`

Answer (score 0):

I dont know your model names, so please replace path with correct names
but it might look like:

```js
businnesModel.find({isDeleted: false})
.populate({
    path: 'reviewModelName',
    model: 'review',
    populate: {
      path: 'reviewArray',
      model: 'singleReviewModelName',
      match: {
        isDeleted : false
      }
    }
 })
```

It should provide you array of `businessModel` documents - even when their singleReviews array will be empty (because all of reviews are deleted, or there was zero reviews). So you have to filter it out in JS.

To avoid filtering in JS, and to do it a bit more efficient way for mongodb, you can go with `aggregate` instead.